# Filter an ImageCollection by difference of two date properties

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, imagery

I have an image collection with two date properties: start and end. I would like to select only those images that are 30 days or more apart between the start and end date. I tried the following but got an error:

```
var datediff_filter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: 30,
  leftField: 'start',
  rightField: 'end'
}).not();
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ee.Filter.maxDifference` filter only works when the `leftField` and `rightField` values are numbers ([reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-filter-maxdifference)). In your case, the values are strings. You could either map over the collection to convert the string dates to milliseconds since unix epoch (`ee.Date(img.get('start')).millis()`) or just calculate the days difference and then filter on the result. Here is how you might do the latter.

```js
// Add the days difference as a property to each collection element.
imgCol = imgCol.map(function(img) {
  var start = ee.Date(img.get('start'));
  var end = ee.Date(img.get('end'));
  var dif = end.difference(start, 'days');
  return img.set('days_dif', dif);
});

// Filter the collection to days difference >= to 30.
var filteredImgCol = imgCol.filter('days_dif >= 30');
```